# Finding Elapsed age in memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

i'am trying to calculate the time elapsed since datastore object was (mem)cached, tried to find a clear memcache method or argument, but it's clearly stated that there is nothing like this though there is another timing inside the get_stats which is oldest_item_age,  but the doc. states ('This is not the amount of time that has elapsed since the item was created.'), any clear method to calculate elapsed time in seconds? i am using the ndb model objects. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is :no

Long answer : you can probably add the datetime stamp of whenever you add the object to memcache to give you an idea of how long ago it was put in there